# css border going from the origin of the tag rather than from the edge of the tag

Tags: css

I have a general question on design and practices for overcoming layout problems. Let's say I have this html:

```
<div class="info">
    <p>some stuff here for the paragraph</p>
</div>
```

and I have this css:

```
.info {
    width: 10%;
    padding-left: 15%;
    border: dashed;
}
```

My question is that the output of this will generate something that has a bigger border than  necessary, are there design practices to avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: I didn't got your question

Comment: @Mr.Alien so if you put that into JSFiddle or something, the border will be much longer that I expected, what is the best way to make closer to the position of the paragraph?

Comment: Give a border width for ex : 1px.

Comment: @user2405469 If you mean the dashes than here you go http://jsfiddle.net/EhVem/

Comment: div is block element and use all width available, reset its display in order to see it shrink on it's content. is that a good guess ? Your question is not clear at all. what bothers you, width, padding, thickness of border, else ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I don't mean the dashes, I mean the fact that the border is longer length ways as opposed to even all round

Comment: @GCyrillus what bothers is the padding, I have padded it further from the left, as a result, is uses all the width available, I wanted to it to use less width

Comment: okay, if you want to include padding within the width given, look at `box-sizing:border-box;` (gecko needs a prefix at this time) http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0

Comment: @GCyrillus thank you, that's kool, I decided to just wrap it in another div and move that...

Comment: @user2405469 I see, there's as well a reset on `margin:0` for `<p>` that you might do.

Comment: @GCyrillus thank you :) nice suggestion, it is a little more manageable that way

Answer (score 0):

There are some other styling methods for border.

like :

border: 1px solid black;

Try this.

Comment: perhaps my question doesn't fully convey my problem, the border with that css I supplied is too long, is there a way to make it closer to the paragraph?

Comment: remove padding-left from css ;)